# Add listview row item into another listview in another fragment

Tags: android, listview, android-fragments

I'm currently using a ViewPager and the ViewPager object has two Fragments. Each fragment contains a listview. The listview on the first fragment has an Add button in each of the row item. The listview on each fragment has its own definition XML files.

Now, when the Add button is pressed, I want the row item corresponding to the Add button to be added into listview of the second Fragment. So that's how I tried to accomplish this:

```
// R.layout.id_number is where the listview layout of the second fragment is defined
View acceptedJob = inflater.inflate(R.layout.id_number, container, false);
ListView listView = (ListView)acceptedJob.findViewById(R.id.listView);
CustomListAdapter adapter = (CustomListAdapter)listView.getAdapter();
adapter.getLists().add(new Orders("Constructor arguments"));
```

However, the adapter variable is null which suggests that listView.getAdapter() returns a null pointer. I'm not sure why that happens. Perhaps my approach is wrong so that's the reason I'm here.

I've heard about FragmentTransaction to let two fragments communicate with each other but I'm exactly sure how to get started.

Thanks.

Comment: have you called listView.setAdapter() before those line?

Comment: Are you trying to communicate between two Fragment?

Comment: Mr.Rao : I did those on the respective fragment's onCreateView method 
Sarhad Salam: In a way yes since I'm passing a listview row item from one fragment to another.